# Subir archivo de Excel a MVC.Net y cargar datos a SQL Server

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de MVC.Net en dónde en una parte de mi proyecto debo hacer la carga de un archivo de Excel y al cargarlo a la vista debo enviarlo a la base de datos. El detalle de esto es que no necesito mostrar la información de ese Excel, solo cargarla ya que son demasiados registros los que contiene el archivo de Excel.

En el controlador tengo tres métodos. Uno de tipo GET y dos de tipo POST. Aquí los muestro.

```
public class FileController : Controller
{

    private OpexDB db = new OpexDB();

    /// <summary>
    /// Nos retorna el documento dentro de la vista CargarArchivo.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult CargarArchivo()
    {
        CargaArchivo modelDocumento = new CargaArchivo();
        return View(modelDocumento);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Función que se encargará de cargar el archivo de Excel en el aplicativo web.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelDocumento"> Variable de tipo CargarArchivo que representa el archivo que se va a obtener </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CargarArchivo(CargaArchivo modelDocumento)
    {

        if (modelDocumento.Documento != null && modelDocumento.Documento.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            using(XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(modelDocumento.Documento.InputStream))
            {
                // Obtener hoja del archivo de Excel.
                var ws = wb.Worksheets.First();

                // No incluimos el encabezado, empieza desde la segunda fila.
                int FirstRow = 2;
            

                // Obtener la última linea del archivo = con datos.
                var lastRow = ws.RowsUsed().Count();

                try
                {
                    for (int row = FirstRow; row <= (int)lastRow; row++)
                    {
                        // Variable que va a iterar cada columna de la clase VMOpexBanco
                        VMOpexBanco model = new VMOpexBanco();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 1).Value != null)
                            model.LineaMc = ws.Cell(row, 1).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 2).Value != null)
                            model.LineaNivel2 = ws.Cell(row, 2).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 3).Value != null)
                            model.LineaNivel3 = ws.Cell(row, 3).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 4).Value != null)
                            model.LineaNivel4 = ws.Cell(row, 4).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 5).Value != null)
                            model.LineaNivel5 = ws.Cell(row, 5).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 6).Value != null)
                            model.Banco = Convert.ToInt16(ws.Cell(row, 6).Value.ToString().Trim());

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 7).Value != null)
                            model.NombreCuenta = ws.Cell(row, 7).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 8).Value != null)
                            model.Cuenta = ws.Cell(row, 8).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 9).Value != null)
                            model.Area = ws.Cell(row, 9).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 10).Value != null)
                            model.CCNombre = ws.Cell(row, 10).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 11).Value != null)
                            model.Descripcion = ws.Cell(row, 11).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 12).Value != null)
                            model.DocumentoSap = (long)Convert.ToDouble(ws.Cell(row, 12).Value.ToString().Trim());

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 13).Value != null)
                            model.Lote = Convert.ToInt16(ws.Cell(row, 13).Value.ToString().Trim());

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 14).Value != null)
                            model.TipoCambio = Convert.ToDecimal(ws.Cell(row, 14).Value.ToString().Trim());

                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ws.Cell(row, 15).Value.ToString()))
                            model.MontoDebito = Convert.ToDecimal(ws.Cell(row, 15).Value.ToString().Trim());

                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ws.Cell(row, 16).Value.ToString()))
                            model.MontoCredito = Convert.ToDecimal(ws.Cell(row, 16).Value.ToString().Trim());

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 17).Value != null)
                        {
                            decimal valor;
                            if (decimal.TryParse(ws.Cell(row, 17).Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out valor))
                            {
                                model.Total = valor;
                            }
                        }
                        


                        if (ws.Cell(row, 18).Value != null)
                            model.Mes = ws.Cell(row, 18).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 19).Value != null)
                            model.Agencia = Convert.ToInt16(ws.Cell(row, 19).Value.ToString().Trim());

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 20).Value != null)
                            model.CentroCosto = Convert.ToInt16(ws.Cell(row, 20).Value.ToString().Trim());

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 21).Value != null)
                            model.CodigoContable = ws.Cell(row, 21).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 22).Value != null)
                            model.CodigoTransaccion = ws.Cell(row, 22).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 23).Value != null)
                            model.Moneda = ws.Cell(row, 23).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 24).Value != null)
                            model.Modelo = ws.Cell(row, 24).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 25).Value != null)
                            model.CCBanco = ws.Cell(row, 25).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 26).Value != null)
                            model.Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(ws.Cell(row, 26).Value.ToString().Trim());

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 27).Value != null)
                            model.Opex = ws.Cell(row, 27).Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (ws.Cell(row, 26).Value != null)
                            model.Año = Convert.ToDateTime(ws.Cell(row, 26).Value.ToString().Trim()).Year;
                        

                        // Las columnas son añadidas a la variable modelDocumento
                        modelDocumento.listVMOpexBanco.Add(model);
                    }

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    // Obtener seguimiento de la pila para excepción.
                    var st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
                    // Obtener marco de pila superior.
                    var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
                    // Obtiene número de linea de marco de la pila.
                    var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
                }

            }
        }

        // Nos retorna el archivo con su información.
        return View(modelDocumento);
    }

    
    /// <summary>
    /// Método que se va a encargar de enviar la información del archivo de Excel hacia nuestra base de datos.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelDocumento">Variable que se representa la información que se obtener a la correspondiente tabla de la base de datos.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CargarSQLServer(CargaArchivo modelDocumento)
    {

        // Si viene la información completa, usar la siguiente instrucción.

        // Variable de tipo list, que representa las columnas de la tabla PRUEBAOPEX.
        var ListOpexBanco = new List<PRUEBAOPEX>();
           
            foreach (var item in modelDocumento.listVMOpexBanco)
            {
            // Iteración con las columnas.
                PRUEBAOPEX model = new PRUEBAOPEX() { 
                    LINEAMC = item.LineaMc,
                    LINEANIVEL2 = item.LineaNivel2,
                    LINEANIVEL3 = item.LineaNivel3,
                    LINEANIVEL4 = item.LineaNivel4,
                    LINEANIVEL5 = item.LineaNivel5,
                    BANCO = item.Banco,
                    NOMBRECUENTA = item.NombreCuenta,
                    CUENTA = item.Cuenta,
                    AREA = item.Area,
                    NOMBRE = item.CCNombre,
                    DESCRIPCION = item.Descripcion,
                    DOCUMENTOSAP = item.DocumentoSap,
                    LOTE = item.Lote,
                    TIPOCAMBIO = item.TipoCambio,
                    MONTODEBITO = item.MontoDebito,
                    MONTOCREDITO = item.MontoCredito,
                    TOTAL = item.Total,
                    MES = item.Mes,
                    AGENCIA = item.Agencia,
                    CENTROCOSTO = item.CentroCosto,
                    CODIGOCONTABLE = item.CodigoContable,
                    CODIGOTRANSACCION = item.CodigoTransaccion,
                    MONEDA = item.Moneda,
                    MODELO = item.Modelo,
                    CCBANCO = item.CCBanco,
                    FECHA = item.Fecha,
                    OPEX = item.Opex,
                    AÑO = item.Año
                };
                  
                  // La información es almacenada a la lista.
                  ListOpexBanco.Add(model);
            }
           
                // La lista es enviada a la db.
                db.BulkInsert(ListOpexBanco);
            
        // Se realiza la carga a la base de datos.
        return View("CargarArchivo", modelDocumento);
    }
}
```

El método CargaArchivo se encarga de leer las columnas y el contenido de la hoja de Excel.
El método CargarSQLServer se encarga de enviar el Excel ya cargado hacía mi base de datos.

Dentro de mi vista solo he encontrado la forma de cargar el archivo mostrándolo por medio de tablas, y tengo el inconveniente de que solo me muestra cierta cantidad limitada de registros.

Muestro lo que tengo de mi vista:

```
@model WebPlantillaOpexLTE.Models.ViewModels.CargaArchivo
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Carga de Archivo de Excel";
}


<div class="container">
<div class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1 class="m-0" style="text-align: justify">Carga de Archivo</h1>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>

<!-- Llamada al método del controlador FileController -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("CargarArchivo", "File", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "dataForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="file" name="Documento" value="Documento" id="Documento" multiple="true" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="submit" value="Vista Previa" class="btn btn-success" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Procesar Datos" class="btn btn-secondary" formaction="/File/CargarSQLServer" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Modelos:

```
public class CargaArchivo
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase Documento { get; set; }

    public List<VMOpexBanco> listVMOpexBanco { get; set; } = new List<VMOpexBanco>();
}

public class VMOpexBanco
{
    public string LineaMc { get; set; }
    public string LineaNivel2 { get; set; }
    public string LineaNivel3 { get; set; }
    public string LineaNivel4 { get; set; }
    public string LineaNivel5 { get; set; }
    public int Banco { get; set; }
    public string NombreCuenta { get; set; }
    public string Cuenta { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string CCNombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public long DocumentoSap { get; set; }
    public int Lote { get; set; }
    public decimal TipoCambio { get; set; }
    public decimal MontoDebito { get; set; }
    public decimal MontoCredito { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string Mes { get; set; }
    public int Agencia { get; set; }
    public int CentroCosto { get; set; }
    public string CodigoContable { get; set; }
    public string CodigoTransaccion { get; set; }
    public string Moneda { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    public string CCBanco { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Opex { get; set; }
    public int Año { get; set; }
}
```

El submit de "Vista Previa" cargará el archivo seleccionado de Excel y el submit "Procesar Datos" enviará los datos del archivo a mi base de datos.

Me gustaría saber que podría hacer para lograr hacer la carga del archivo sin necesidad de mostrar datos del mismo, poder cargar todos los registros y de esa forma trasladarlo a mi base de datos. ¿Qué debería agregar a mi vista?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo.... que pasa cuando presionas `Procesar Datos` SIN haber presionado `Vista Previa` ???

Comment: No pasa nada. Me asegure de poner un breakpoint en ese método y no entra al foreach, directamente al bulkinsert. Por lo tanto la información del Excel no se traslada a la base de datos. No sé a qué se deberá.

Comment: Pasa en ambos casos. Cuando no selecciono Vista Previa o cuando la selecciono. En Vista Previa tras seleccionar el archivo, si lee cada uno de los registros.

Answer (score 0):

Está algo enredado el asunto, tienes un modelo que no entiendo del todo a que apunta (sé que es para mostrar el preview) pero no logro entender cómo va dentro el archivo

Así que lo mejor es simplificar el asunto, prueba esto y me avisas:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CargarArchivo(IFormFile Documento )
{
  if (Documento != null && Documento.Length> 0)
  {
    using(XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(archivo.OpenReadStream()))
    {

    //el resto
```

Comment: Probé de esa manera y me genera error de sintaxis en algunas propiedades, en la parte donde añado la lista ya cargada a la variable Documento. He agregado los modelos que estoy utilizando, me disculpo por no haberlos compartido antes.

Comment: @maguilar puedes mostrarme una foto de esos errores?

Comment: Entendido. Lo agregaré en conjunto de la pregunta.

Comment: Ya puse captura.